# .h5 file can not be read after running out of disk space during write

Tags: python, h5py

I was building an h5 file iteratively with a pretty long process, but ran out of disk space without realizing it.
Now, here is what happens when I now try to read the file content:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('[...].h5','r')
>>> f['imgpath'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/home/[...]/anaconda3/envs/[...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 496, in __getitem__
    self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype, dxpl=self._dxpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 181, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 130, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 84, in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread
OSError: Can't read data (addr overflow, addr = 97708321636, size = 2096, eoa = 12745416)
>>> list(f.keys())
['aligned', 'imgpath', 'transform', 'landmarks']
```

My h5py version:

```
$ conda list h5py
# packages in environment at /home/[...]/anaconda3/envs/[...]:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
h5py                      2.8.0            py37h989c5e5_3
```

Is there any way to recover from this? (Note that my OS also considers the file to be 13M instead of what I would expect: ~100G)

Comment: No telling the state of the file if you ran out of disk space while creating it. Likely it didn't close properly and is corrupted. Try one of the command line tools to interrogate the file. These include `h5dump` from **The HDF Group**, or `ptdump` from  **PyTables**. You could also try to open with `HDFView` or `h5repack` from **The HDF Group**. These will also fail if the file is corrupted.

Comment: The output from `h5dump` is: `h5dump error: internal error (file h5dump.c:line 1493)`. I take it the data cannot be recovered?

Comment: That's my interpretation. It's difficult to properly close a file when you run out of disk space while creating it.

Comment: It would have been nice if the library could simply leave the file at the state of the previous successful flush, instead of corrupting all of the content.